# Zuul routing of header information

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I noticed that the zuul seems only to pass on the unique HTTP headers.

There is a case where I have two headers with the same key name but different values and it only passes the first one of that name and not the second.

I noticed initially that I sonly got the first header and when I switched the order again the first order but the other one.

Is this expected behaviour?  The RFC supports multiple headers with the same key

Any way to support the passing off multiple headers of the same key name?

Comment: Looks like a bug in the filter to me. Please open an issue in github.

Comment: ok let me put together a test case

Comment: submitted: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/260